# Remove SocialBlade from my YouTube Channel

Tags: youtube

I have a YouTube channel and there is a SocialBlade page on my channel. My channel is for educational purposes and I do not want a SocialBlade page. Please advise the steps that I should follow to remove the SocialBlade page.

Answer (score 2):

From [Social Blade's terms](https://socialblade.com/info/terms):

> SOCIAL BLADE WILL NOT DELETE OR REMOVE PUBLIC INFORMATION FROM OUR DATABASE UNLESS WE RECEIVE A LEGALLY-BINDING ORDER TO DO SO.

The only way to remove your channel from Social Blade appears to be by somehow getting a court order or something similar.

Comment: A bit late, but for people that see this later. Deleting your channel will _not_ result in Social Blade taking the page down. I was actually looking into this because I found Social Blade is still hosting pages for all of my old channels I had in the past and had deleted years ago.